# Capture a screenshot and convert it into a base64 String

Tags: java, base64, encode, screen-capture, awtrobot

Purpose of publishing this question is to help the armature coders and all to get out of the following problems *(I found some misleading answers from the internet for the bellow problems)*

- Capture a desktop Image by Java robot
- Image **convert/encode** to the **base64 String**

Answer code is published by my self and guarantee the for 100% working state

Comment: Please stick to *one* topic per post. Capturing a desktop image and converting data into base64 are *entirely* separate things.

Comment: Can you help to post a C# version? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion no need to create `BufferedImage` keep it simply like :

```
public String captureToBase64() {

    Rectangle screenSize = new 
    Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    BufferedImage screenCapture = null;
    String base64Encoded = "";

    try {

        screenCapture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenSize);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(screenCapture, "jpg", baos);
        baos.flush();
        byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64(baos.toByteArray());
        base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64);
        baos.close();

    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }

    return base64Encoded;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Here is the answer**

Your need the following java imports

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
```

and the method as follow

```
public final String takeScreenshot() {
    String base64 = "";
    try {

        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        BufferedImage capture;

        capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);

        BufferedImage bufferedThumbnail = new BufferedImage(capture.getWidth(null), capture.getHeight(null),
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        bufferedThumbnail.getGraphics().drawImage(capture, 0, 0, null);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(bufferedThumbnail, "png", baos);
        baos.flush();
        byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
        byte[] encodedArr = Base64.encodeBase64(imageInByte);
        // base64 = encodedArr.toString();
        base64 = new String(encodedArr);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error While Getting Screen Shot" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return base64;
}
```

Comment: a) that error handling is poor: you'll return an empty string if anything goes wrong. b) You haven't given any indication where the `Base64` class comes from. (There may well be better options that don't involve going via a byte array for no reason.) c) you're using the system default encoding, which *probably* isn't going to cause problems, but might on (say) an EBCDIC machine.  d) as a matter of style, I'd definitely assign to `capture` in the declaration - why separate the two statements?

Comment: Oh, and why are you creating a thumbnail? That looks entirely unnecessary. If it *is* necessary for some reason, you should explain *why* it's necessary. Code-only posts aren't nearly as useful as actual explanations.